# Azure Storage account doesn't have "Europe" Affinity / Location group?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I just created a web app on North EU Azure datacenter.

When I try to add an affinity group on the Settings on manage.windowsazure.com page I only see:

**South & Central & East US, Southeast Asia, Japan West.**

I see the same list when I am trying to create a Storage Account or trying to create a VM.

When creating a Mobile Service I see North EU, creating a Cloud Service the same previous list without EU and with Batch Service I see a long list of data centers.

But when I go to portal.azure.com I was able to create a storage account in North EU. Then now I can't see this in the manage.windowsazure.com.

I am really confused. Is this how it should be?

Thanks

Comment: I see North Europe in my list of Affinity group. What kind of subscription is this on? Is it a paid subscription, an Enterprise Agreement one or a trial?

Comment: @MikeWo it is currently in trial, I've provided my credit card information etc so it will be paid subscription next month. Would being in trial has any effect?

Comment: I actually had a trial version and I also couldn't see Europe as region, too. Today is my first day with normal pay service and I still can't find Europe in my list of Affinity group.

Comment: I believe that some Trial accounts are limited to what regions they can deploy things to, but I don't think it would be limited to just Affinity Groups. I'd think you'd also not be able to deploy anything to those regions. Note that for the storage account you created in the portal.azure.com check to see is under Storage Account (Classic), if it isn't then it was created using Azure Resource Manager and won't be visible to the old portal.

Comment: Try this if you have the Azure PowerShell cmdlets installed. Use Add-AzureAccount to authenticate, then use select-azuresubscription to set the correct subscription to your trial account. Then run Get-AzureLocation | ft -Property DisplayName  See what lists of Regions is shows.

Comment: Trial and MSDN subscriptions may not have access to all services in all regions, for capacity planning reasons

Comment: @MikeWo thank you very much. I ran those commands and I see that my account is restricted to some regions. I sent an Account related support ticket and let's see what's going to happen.
Result of the command: 
DisplayName
-----------
East US
South Central US
Central US
Southeast Asia
Japan West

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike Wo mentioned, if you created an account using Resource Manager (instead of Classic), this will not show up in the old portal. If you can't see the option to create a North EU storage account in the old portal, you should create a support request ticket to figure out if your subscription has certain limitations.